# How to reverse proxy a host with apache that is behind a forward proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, http-proxy

If you have a host that is only reachable through a forward proxy and wish to access it through an application, that does not support proxies - how do you set up an reverse proxy in a virtual host of an apache, which is reachable by the application?

That is, the application accesses http://myapache:myvirtualhost/ , from which myapache accesses the remote application by forwardproxy:forwardport .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to set up the apache on myapache with:

```
Listen 12345

<VirtualHost *:12345>
  ProxyRemote http http://forwardproxy:5432
  <Location />
      ProxyPass http://remoteapp:9876/
      ProxyPassReverse /
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The remote application http://remoteapp:9876/ is reverse-proxied as http://myapache:12345 . If something connects http://myapache:12345 , the request is proxied by http://forwardproxy:5432